# Excel global formula for blank cell validation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created rather complex report with multiple formulas. To keep the report clean, I decided **not to show** formula results if a certain cell is blank.

**QUESTION:**
Is there any way to *'incorporate'* that check to every single formula on the said worksheet OR do I always have to do a **isblank** check for every single formula I am writing?

---

Comment: You'd need to always do an **isblank** check for every formula.

Comment: I do this for grades that are not available using one cell with off/on and an if() statement of the form if(A1="on", calculation,"")...

Answer (score 0):

Since about Excel for Mac 2011 you have the option of a workaround, which is to blend the formatting of cells containing a formula into their background, with conditional formatting. The usual approach is to turn cell content white, on a white background. With say A4 to be the cell that either is or is not blank a CF formula rule of something like:

```
 =AND(ISBLANK($A$4),ISFORMULA(A1))
```

with white fill should work for a range starting in A1.